# Postgres - ´after update´ trigger doesn't fire

Tags: postgresql, triggers, auto-update

I have this table for which one of the columns is to be filled with values from other columns of the same table (these other columns represent a taxonomic hierarchy whose lowest level I wish to store in this other column).

To achieve this I implemented the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_taxon()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
   BEGIN
    UPDATE taxon SET taxon = coalesce(subespecie, especie, genero, subfamilia, familia, infraordem, subordem, ordem, superordem, subclasse, classe, subphylum, phylum, reino )
    WHERE taxon IS NULL;
    RETURN NEW;
   END
$BODY$
VOLATILE; 

CREATE TRIGGER update_taxon
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON taxon
    FOR EACH STATEMENT  
    WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) -- Prevent recursive trigger calls
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_taxon();
```

When I insert a new record the trigger works as expected, but if I update an existing record, nothing happens - the trigger just ignores UPDATE operations and I don't know why.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your statement trigger first fired all records in the table should have their `taxon` field updated with the best available information. When you update a record you may want to update the `taxon` value, but you are better off with a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE FOR EACH ROW` trigger. The only new data is contained in the row for which the trigger fires, of course. So try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_taxon()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  NEW.taxon := coalesce(NEW.subespecie, NEW.especie, NEW.genero, NEW.subfamilia, 
                        NEW.familia, NEW.infraordem, NEW.subordem, NEW.ordem, NEW.superordem,
                        NEW.subclasse, NEW.classe, NEW.subphylum, NEW.phylum, NEW.reino);
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ VOLATILE; 

CREATE TRIGGER update_taxon
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON taxon
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_taxon();
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick! That worked like a charm! One question though. It is not clear for me, even after reading the official Postgres documentation, why a BEFORE trigger is better than an AFTER in this case. As far as I understand in the case of BEFORE the trigger is fired before the associated event is committed to the database, but in cases like this one isn't that the same as firing the trigger after the events are committed to the database?